# Using Adobe Air or Flex to connect to a server/php file for database interaction

Tags: php, actionscript-3, flash, http, flash-builder

I will be developing an smartphone app (eg iOS) in either actionscript 3 with adobe air or using flex. However I need to connect to a database for a huge amount of data storage and retrieval. There is a tonne of information about local database storage, but not on an external server!

I have done some research, most leads me to dead ends or not to be what I need. I have heard that its safer to pass variables to a PHP file which then deals with the database stuff; however how can I send data from the actionscript file over to a server and target php file? I cannot seem to find this anywhere!

At the moment I do not have an code to show, I am trying to find the best solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best is not to just call php scripts, but to build a php based webservice.
You can achieve that by using AMFPhp

Please check the links below on what you can do and how.

http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_AMFPHP___Flex_4_demo-16508.html

http://polygeek.com/530_video-tutorial_amfphp-video-tutorial-connecting-to-amfphp-and-returning-data-version-10

http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/